# Noetherian module over noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a noetherian module over noetherian ring $A$.

How to prove that there exists submodule $N\subset M$ such that
$$M/N\cong A/\mathfrak{p}$$
for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in A$.

Is it true that any submodule of noetherian module over noetherian ring is noetherian? (because it is finitely generated as submodule of noetherian module?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you see what happens if you take M' maximal?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: any maximal? any "limit" of ascending chain?

Comment: In fact the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ can be taken maximal: choose $N$ maximal in the set of proper submodules of $M$ (why there is such $N$?); then $M/N$ is a simple module, so...

Answer (score 2):

Hints for the main question: (under the assumption your ring has unity)

1. $M/N$ is a simple module when $N$ is a maximal submodule.
2. A simple module is isomorphic to $R/I$ for some maximal ideal $I\lhd R$.
3. You probably are aware of some relationship between maximal and prime ideals...

You should be able to reason out why the submodules of a Noetherian module $M$ over *any* ring are Noetherian. Consider an ascending chain in the submodule $N\subseteq M$ ... and remember it is a chain in $M$ too!

Comment: @navigetor23 Anyone who defines "maximal submodule" and allows $M$ to be considered is wasting their time. That is why the overwhelming majority of sources require *by definition* maximal submodules to be proper submodules.

Comment: A maximal submodule may not exist :). @navigator23: you are wasting your time deletting comments and answers :).

Comment: @qiL Of course a maximal submodule *must* exist: the module is Noetherian.

Comment: not always, even for Noetherian module. :) OK I will say why in a few hours if nobody notices the problem in the statement of the OP.

Comment: @QiL Well under reasonable assumptions like the axiom of choice, "Noetherian" is equivalent to having the maximal condition on any subset of its submodules, so I choose the set to be the proper submodules and I have maximal submodules.

Comment: Dear rschwieb, sorry for wasting your time. The point is $M$ must be non-zero. Assuming the axiome of choice, the existence of maximal submodules is valid over any ring, provided that $M\ne 0$ (not necessarily finitely generated) ! This is like the existence of a maximal ideal in a non-zero ring.

Comment: @QiL You're right that it is a waste of time. I prefer not to get hung up on things like this unless they're critical. Posters frequently miss hypotheses much more important than this, and it's OK to make little assumptions.